# Module Builds view is not shown in Jenkins with "withMaven" block with Pipeline scripts

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkinsfile using groovy syntax, something like this:

```
pipeline {

  ... truncated ...

  stages {
    stage {
      steps {
        withMaven() {
          sh "mvn clean install ..."
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The build page (job/job_name/37) has a Deployed Artifacts view/section of what artifacts Maven has been built and deployed, but it does not have the Module Builds view like when doing a Freestyle Jenkins job using maven build step. The Module Builds view has what module has been built and the time spent on building it.

How can I turn this feature on for maven builds with Pipeline?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no equivalent of the module view when using the Pipeline Maven integration. Which information of the "module view" are you interested in? Is it primarily the time spent in each module?

Comment: @CyrilleLeClerc Indeed it is the time spent in each module. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging, the Module Builds view is only available for maven-plugin. This plugin is not used when using a Pipeline, the maven plugin for Pipeline is called pipeline-maven-plugin and it does not implement this feature.

Comment: We have converted some builds to pipeline and wanted to convert our multi-module maven build. However, without the module view it seems a significant loss of information. Thanks for doing the research and saving me the time.